# How to change the color, or remove, the vertical line next to the scroll bar?

Tags: colors, fringe

When I try some themes like the `doom-nord-light` theme, I get some weird line on the side of the scroll bar (here in yellow, but sometimes it is black):

[image]

How can I could remove them or change their color to match the background color or the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it is the fringe.

Try:

```
(custom-set-faces
 `(fringe ((t (:background "blue")))))
```

Comment: Oh indeed, thanks a lot! They also seem to disappear when `t (:backgound "blue")` is replaced with `nil`, not sure if it's the proper way to do that.

Comment: Btw, do you know if there is a list of all the possible colors customizable by themes?

Comment: Also, just realized that solarized has a special `solarized-distinct-fringe-background` to disable fringe.

Comment: `M-x list-colors`?

Comment: Note that the above code will write to the custom file, and is likely to be loaded even if you change its value in your `init.el` file (I spent some time to understand why fringes were back everytime I was restarting emacs). To change is without saving them into custom, I used `(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background nil)`